# How to reference a global scope variable into the local scope?

Tags: javascript

```
var b=1;

function someFunc(b) {
     //here 
}
```

I want to be able to reference the variable b that is defined outside the function. How can this be done in javascript?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to access it via the `global object`, which is `window` in a browser and `global` in node.js for instance.

```
var b=1;

function someFunc(b) {
    alert( window.b ); // or console.log( global.b );
}
```

Why ? Well, the such called *Activation Object* (in ES3) or the *Lexical Environment Record* (ES5) will overlap the variable name `b`. So anytime a JS engine resolves `b` it'll stop at the first occurence, which is in its own Scope.

Comment: What would the global object in a non-DOM environment like node.js?

Comment: `global` in node.js is not a real global object!

Comment: @RajSekharan although `global.b` is the way to go, why not change the variable names?  I use `_b` for variables private to a module.

Comment: Yes, using appropriate naming conventions seems the appropriate way. Needed to better understand resolving scope properly.

Comment: @Niko: `global` and `GLOBAL` reference the global object in node.js, which reference the `Variable Object`.