# Update variable sent to ajax call with value from previous ajax response

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have an ajax function that executes every 3 seconds, calling a 'file2.php' file. I pass a variable $lastid through POST, use it in 'file2.php' and then in the response i get a new last id, which I need to send as $lastid the next time the ajax function executes. But I can't find a way to update the variable that actually replaces the previous value in the ajax call.

I have tried assigning response.lastid to var lastid inside the ajax function but it doesn't help. I keep getting the same response I got in the previous call, eternally.

This is the ajax function and how I set the variable initially

```
<script>
var lastid = <?php echo $lastid; ?>;

function nuevospedidos() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.open("POST", "file2.php", true);
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      var response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      console.log(response);
      var lastid = response.lastid;
    }
  };
  xhttp.send("lastid=" + lastid);

}
setInterval(nuevospedidos, 3000);
</script>
```

The response I get is this JSON object

```
{lastid: "4074",
contenido: "some content",
originalid: "4073"}
```

I would like to receive that response only once, and then update the lastid variable with the lastid that the JSON object brings, so that the next time it executes it knows that was the last id processed.

Comment: Get rid of `var` in the callback function. You're setting a local variable instead of the global variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a scope issue. Your `lastid` variable is not global when [declared inside a function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#Description).

You must declare it as a global variable:

```
var lastid = <?php echo $lastid ?>;
function newId() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("POST", "file2.php", true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            var response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            lastid = response.lastid;
        }
    };
    xhttp.send("lastid=" + encodeURIComponent(lastid));
}
setInterval(newId, 3000);
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! The problem with this is that the first time the function executes, i have to send the lastid that i got from php in my index file. and only after the second time it executes i have to send  "encodeURIComponent(lastid)". Any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: It should always be `encodeURIComponent(lastid)`. @Ariel

Answer (score 0):

You can use the window object to specify that you are accessing the global variable

```
window.lastid = response.lastid;
```

As explained here: [How to reference a global scope variable into the local scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10178307/how-to-reference-a-global-scope-variable-into-the-local-scope)

Comment: if this alone doesn't work try adding the window in the original var declaration too

Comment: And also in the xhttp.send line, just in case